# Fetching Facebook Open Graph Data via NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, nsurlrequest

How can I retrieve data from the Graph API using `NSMutableURLRequest`?

I already have a valid access token and I need to fetch basic user information such as birthday, ID, picture or first/last name.

In the accounts framework you can create a request with parameters using `+ requestForServiceType:requestMethod:URL:parameters:` so I just tried `- setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` but it doesn't seem to work...

As long as I write all the necessary attributes in the request URL it works fine. Maybe there is a request URL scheme I can use or any other way to submit the attributes needed to perform the request.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple GET request and include the access_token like this. You can insert the ACCESS_TOKEN using [NSString stringWithFormat:]

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=id,name,birthday"]]];
```